# how to set listener for imagebutton to notice when touched position moved out or moved into the imagebutton?

Tags: java, android, listener

I am making a simple piano app for android with java, I just set `setOnTouchedListener` to each `ImageButtons`. if `MotionEvent` is `ACTION_DOWN`, The piano sound played. and if `MotionEvent` is `ACTION_UP`, The piano sound stopped. But if I drag my finger out of `ImageButton`, the sound still playing.
I want to make the sound stopped when I drag my finger out of `ImageButton`.
and If I drag into `ImageButton`, I want the sound is played again...
what listener should I use?

```
public class KeyBoardListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private SoundPool spool;
    private int soundkeys[];
    private int pitch;
    private boolean isWhite;
    public void setInitSound(SoundPool spool, int soundkeys[], int pitch, boolean isWhite){ // 리스너에서 재생할 SoundPool 가져옴
        this.soundkeys=soundkeys;
        this.spool=spool;
        this.pitch=pitch;
        this.isWhite=isWhite;
    }
        @Override       // 건반 이미지뷰 터치리스너
        public boolean onTouch (View view, MotionEvent motionEvent){
            int currentpitch=pitch+KeyboardActivity.octave.get()*12;     // 옥타브 값 적용
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                float y = motionEvent.getY();   // 터치한 Y좌표와 건반 최대 Y좌표 이용해 벨로시티 값 계산
                float ymax=view.getHeight();
                y=y/ymax;
                PlayNote.noteOff(spool, currentpitch);
                PlayNote.noteOn(spool, soundkeys[currentpitch], currentpitch, y);
                if(isWhite)
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#B0B0B0"));
                else
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.key_black_push);
            }
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (KeyboardActivity.sustain.get() == false)  // 서스테인 기능이 꺼져있을 때만 소리 정지
                    PlayNote.noteOff(spool, currentpitch);
                if(isWhite)
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                else
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.key_black);
            }
            return false;
        }

}
```